# udev: how can I extend a default rule to modify the ownership of a symlink?

Tags: linux, udev

I need to get some USB-serial devices into a particular user group to access them from an application.  This is straightforward for the /dev/ttyUSB devices, where I can just use `KERNEL="ttyUSB*", GROUP:="mygroup"`.  However, for the symlinks like /dev/bus/usb/001/001, it is not obvious how to accomplish the same thing of setting their group to `mygroup`.  I can do it by editing the default rules file `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-udev.rules` and adding a `GROUP="mygroup"` clause to the line for usb_device which creates the symlinks in /dev/bus/usb, however editing this file is clearly suboptimal from a packaging point of view.

So: how can I write a udev rule to modify the ownership of a symlink created by an earlier, default udev rule?

(I'm working on CentOS 5.5.)

Answer (score 2):

Answered my own question: apparently it's all about using `:=` instead of `=`.

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", MODE:="0664", GROUP:="mygroup"`

This goes in a 10-usb-devices.rules file in /etc/udev/rules.d.  The ":=" gets it to override the permissions of the nodes that the other rule creates -- I had initially incorrectly thought it was creating symlinks when in fact it was creating actual nodes in /dev/bus.

Answer (score 0):

I was confronted to your problem 2 years ago (centos 4) and the only solution I've found was also to modify the udev rules. But I've created a specific file for it. Have you tried to create a 49-mydev.rules with your specific device ?

Answer (score -1):

Symbolic link ownership shouldn't matter, only the ownership of the file that the link points to.